# CNN training out of RAM cause by big dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a big image dataset of around 30000+ images. My system is out of RAM when I train the model, I don't want to downsample the dataset. Is there any way I can fix this issue?

```
#set up the inizilize integer
batch_size = 16
img_height = 512
img_width = 512
color_mode = 'rgba'

#split the dataset into training testing and validation
#load the dataset as categorical label type
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  train_dir,
  labels='inferred', 
  label_mode='categorical',
  color_mode=color_mode,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  train_dir,
  labels='inferred', 
  label_mode='categorical',
  color_mode=color_mode,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)


train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

cnn_model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 4)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  #layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(5,activation="softmax")
])
cnn_model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
  loss=tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
  metrics=['accuracy','Recall','Precision','AUC']
  )

def model_train(model,patience,namemodel):
    #call back for earlystopping
    callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=patience)
    #tensorboard call back for profile
    tboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = log_dir,
                                                     histogram_freq = 1,
                                                     profile_batch = '500,520')

    model_save_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath=save_dir+'pd/'+namemodel,
        save_weights_only=False,
        monitor='val_loss',
        mode='min',
        save_best_only=True)

    history = model.fit(  
      train_ds,
      validation_data=val_ds,
      epochs=1000,
      callbacks=[callback,model_save_callback],
      batch_size = batch_size
    )
    return history


history = model_train(cnn_model,30,'cnn_v1'.format(img_height,color_mode,batch_size))
```

I know there is a way like I can send 30000+ images part by part to the model. But I don't know how to do that. Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: The easiest way is to just reduce your batch_size

Comment: Why is there a `4` in `input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 4)`?

Comment: because they are 4 channel png images

Answer (score 1):

When you use image_dataset_from_directory the images and labels are fetched for training in batches. In your case you set the batch size to 16. So only 16 images and labels are loaded into memory at any one time versus loading all 30000. If you are still getting an Out of Memory error you can reduce the batch size but unless you have a really small memory a batch size of 16 should be OK. You might consider reducing the image size. A 512 X 512 image in rgba format has about 1,000,000 pixels to process which will use up a lot of memory. Try  256  X 256 which would be on the order of 275K pixels or better yet 128 X 128 which is only about 65K pixels. I am not sure what the effect is of the caching, but I expect it is also increasing memory use since I believe it is fetching the next batch into memory while the network is training. Try removing those two lines of code and see if the problem goes away.